# CDF and PDF in the case of normal distribution

Tags: probability

I was reviewing some really basic probability and came across a statement that confused me.

> We write X ∼ N(μ, σ^2) to denote that p(X = x) = N(x|μ, σ^2). If X ∼ N(0, 1), we
> say X follows a standard normal distribution.
>
> We will often talk about the precision of a Gaussian, by which we mean
> the inverse variance: λ = 1/σ^2. A high precision means a narrow
> distribution (low variance) centered on μ. Note that, since this is a
> pdf, we can have p(x) > 1. To see this, consider evaluating the
> density at its center, x = μ. We have N(μ|μ, σ^2) = (σ√2π)−1e^0, so if σ
> < 1/√2π, we have p(x) > 1.

Here, I can get my head around everything except that I am not sure how to interpret the case where p(x) > 1.

If I'm reading the statements correctly, as variance gets smaller, the probability of mean should get higher,which makes sense, but I do not see how the probability exceeds one.

Comment: $p(x)$  is not a probbability. It can be greater than $1$ or less than $1$.

Comment: Also, $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: You have to integrate the PDF over an interval(s) to get the probability that the normal random variable lies in that interval(s). The probability that the random variable is equal to any number is zero. Note that for a PDF $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)~dx=1$ and since $p$ is positive we get the probability over an subinterval is less than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $p(x)$ doesn't indicate a probability but  "probability density". In fact for a continuous rv you have a pdf and not a pmf .

The probability is defined only in a range $(a;b)$ and it is the integral $\int_a^b p(x)dx$

This is an example of Gaussian density with mean 0 and $\sigma=0.1$

[image]